# Creating Test Accounts for Compatibility of an App

Tags: unit-test, lightning

Need some help creating test accounts that use the various SF subscription levels (Unlimited, Group, Professional, Enterprise, Performance) to test compatibility of our app.

I have created Test Orgs of Enterprise, Partner, Consulting, etc. but cannot set a tested subscription package level(s) (for example Unlimited).

These test orgs pull the same email address from our ISV account.

So for testing we end up unable to test more than 1-2 accounts with SSO that have unique emails.This reverts the test account back to a previous account that was used with the ISV email address.

PS: I have read all the documentation from SF: https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/214/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_packaging_guide.pdf - a

So my question to the group: 
1. Can you create orgs that reflect the Salesforce subscription levels?
2. Can you change the email addresses used to create test orgs? 
3. Is there another to test your apps connection to SF user accounts?

Answer (score 1):

*There's no need to test every single version*. Every higher version is incrementally better than the version below it in all ways (more API calls, more features, etc). To create new orgs, log in to the Partner Portal and create your orgs from there.

There are several different types of orgs you can create, mentioned [in the documentation](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/general/Partner_Orgs), that are unique to ISV and consultants. They are:

- Partner Developer Edition
- Partner Test (Enterprise/Platform Edition)
- Partner Test (Professional Edition)
- Partner Test (Group Edition)
- Consulting Partner Edition (For Demos)

You must be successfully onboarded to the Partner Program in order to gain access to these orgs. You can create as many as you like (within reason) for any testing/development purpose you like. You will have unique logins for each new org you create. Even though the email address may be the same on multiple users, each org will have a unique login. You can use the Environment Hub feature to keep track of all your created orgs.

---

> Can you create orgs that reflect the Salesforce subscription levels?

Only for the above-mentioned types. You can't create Unlimited/Performance Edition orgs because they're simply not necessary. If you can run in Enterprise, you can run in Unlimited.

> Can you change the email addresses used to create test orgs?

Yes, and you can also change the user name, if you desire. Just be aware that by doing so, if you lose this information, you may not be able to log back in to that org.

> Is there another to test your apps connection to SF user accounts?

You could test it in a normal Developer Edition, a Scratch Org, etc, but the official way to do so is by using the Partner Portal to create orgs for the appropriate purpose.

Comment: So when you say "each org will have a unique log in," even using that the Single Sign On is pulling the Partner Account master (account owner) email address. That email was already used for a different test account. Is there another way to log in and bypass this?

Comment: @StevenWagner You should be using the Environment Hub to log in to the various linked organizations.